# Given a pallette of pseudo-CMYK for output, how can I calculate what input CMYK values are needed to get a certain color?

Tags: calculus

I have a Dell 1250c color printer (very old), and am using Fedora 38, which basically means the only driver I have is [this unofficial one,](https://github.com/macos2/HBPLv1.0_Plus-Printer-driver) which does not have good color calibration options afaik. For some reason, it is not printing true colors. For example, the blue looks more like indigo or perrywinkle. I've successfully printed and scanned a handmade test page to reference on my computer what RGB it is actually printing for input colors of pure cyan, magenta, yellow, black, red, green, and blue. Given these known values of output for input, how can I calculate what color value to put in to get a given output, or at least as close as I can? I intend to apply this to whole images using Python 3 with the PIL Image module, but just a calculus function for one color will probably do.

Here are the RGB values of the colors after printing and re-scanning them:

- Cyan: (178, 233, 241)
- Magenta: (213, 135, 178)
- Yellow: (251, 251, 110)
- Black: (28, 27, 24)
- Red: (243, 126, 72)
- Green: (161, 207, 100)
- Blue: (100, 117, 173)
- Paper: (255, 255, 254)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you have the actual RGB numbers for those 7 colors (plus white, i.e., the blank page)?

Comment: @Dan yes. I'll add them...

Comment: Right now, it seems like the default ICM color profile for the printer was causing the issue. No ICM color correction seems to be better?

Answer (score 0):

Let's model your printer's color distortion as:

$$\vec{a} = D\vec{n} + \vec{k}$$

Where:

- $\vec{n}$ is the nominal color of a pixel, expressed as RGB values.
- $\vec{a}$ is the actual color as it appears after printing and scanning.
- $D$ is a matrix of distortion coefficients.
- $\vec{k}$ is the actual color corresponding to $\vec{n} = 0$ (black).

But we are given that $\vec{k} = (28, 27, 24)$, so let's rewrite the equation as:

$$\vec{a} - \vec{k} = D\vec{n}$$

Plugging in the numbers for the other 7 basic colors, we get:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
150 & 185 & 223 & 215 & 133 & 72 & 227 \\
206 & 108 & 224 & 99 & 180 & 90 & 228 \\
217 & 154 & 86 & 48 & 76 & 149 & 230
\end{bmatrix}
= D\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 255 &255 & 255 & 0 & 0 & 255 \\
255 & 0 & 255 & 0 & 255 & 0 & 255 \\
255 & 255 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 255 & 255
\end{bmatrix}$$

This is an overdetermined system, but if we right-multiply by $N^T$, we get the nice square system:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
216750 & 186915 & 161670 \\
168045 & 213690 & 161160 \\
132090 & 155295 & 191250
\end{bmatrix} = D \begin{bmatrix}
260100 & 130050 & 130050\\
130050 & 260100 & 130050\\
130050 & 130050 & 260100
\end{bmatrix}$$

Which has the solution:

$$D = \begin{bmatrix}
1183/2040 & 143/408 & 319/2040 \\
169/680 & 1223/2040 & 133/680 \\
13/136 & 559/2040 & 1123/2040
\end{bmatrix}$$

So now we have a formula to approximate an on-paper color ($\vec{a}$) given a nominal on-screen color ($\vec{n}$).  But we need it the other way around.

$$\vec{n} = D^{-1}(\vec{a} - \vec{k}) = D^{-1}\vec{a} - D^{-1}\vec{k}$$
$$\vec{n} \approx \begin{bmatrix}
2.292284 & -1.244637 & -0.208930 \\
-0.979484 & 2.523261 & -0.618278 \\
0.089524 & -1.039892 & 2.160604
\end{bmatrix}\vec{a}
 - \begin{bmatrix}29.453431 \\ 27.839706 \\ 23.286765\end{bmatrix}$$

So just plug in the RGB values for the desired on-paper color, and you'll get the nominal RGB values required to print that color.  Though, you may end up with numbers less than 0 or greater than 255, and will need to clip them within the valid range.

Or in Python code (avoiding dependency on any third-party matrix libraries):

```
def clip(x, lo, hi):
    if x < lo:
        x = lo
    elif x > hi:
        x = hi
    return x

def adjust(r, g, b):
    # Calculate the desired color.
    new_r = 2.292284 * r - 1.244637 * g - 0.208930 * b - 29.453431
    new_g = -0.979484 * r + 2.523261 * g - 0.618278 * b - 27.839706
    new_b = 0.089524 * r - 1.039892 * g + 2.160604 * b - 23.286765
    # Constrain the values to integers between 0 and 255
    new_r = clip(round(new_r), 0, 255)
    new_g = clip(round(new_g), 0, 255)
    new_b = clip(round(new_b), 0, 255)
    return (new_r, new_g, new_b)
```

For example, suppose you want the printed paper to use the orange color #FFA500, or (255, 165, 0) in decimal.

```
>>> adjust(255, 165, 0)
(255, 139, 0)
```

So you'll need to use a slightly less green in your printed image to make the color come out right from your printer.

Comment: I just learned about matrices recently. I could not find any resources on what "right-multiplying by Nt" means, and I also do not know exactly how to multiply a tuple by a matrix. I'm guessing I treat it like a vector? But anyways, thank you. If you could explain those bits, I'd like to try and turn this into a Python script that can do the same with future color values of other printers.

Comment: Something is wrong here. I tried using numpy to do it myself, then saw and used your code, but in both cases the printed cyan (178, 233, 241) comes out (without clipping) as (38, 237, 271) when it should be (0, 255, 255). It also appears to be making the pictures darker instead of lighter.

Comment: Well, like I said, this is an overdetermined system.  You've got 24 data points (RGB components for 8 colors) to determine 12 coefficients in the function.  So it's impossible to fit everything exactly, only approximate.   Maybe the linear approximation model is too simplistic.

Comment: Maybe try taking your question to https://unix.stackexchange.com/ and see if there's a more direct way to configure your printer's color calibration in CUPS?

Comment: Maybe forget the RGB values and only deal with the actual CMYK values of the nominal C M Y and K to start with. I kinda just put those in to demonstrate how off the colors looked.

Comment: I have absolutely no hope in being able to calibrate this printer with CUPS, but I guess it’s worth a try.

Comment: Just to clarify, I dodn't mean that sarcastically. Anyway, I looked into matrices and linear transformation, and I believe one should indeed use CMYK, because that way pure white is the origin. Testing that theory now.